# SQL Server - set column in one table to true if column is true in any matching row in another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a SQL update command to set the value of a boolean column in one table based on whether it is true in any child record in another table.

This is part of a database migration - the column on the child table is being replaced by a column on the parent table.

The following SQL works for PostgreSQL

```
UPDATE parenttable 
SET booleanColumn
= EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM childtable
    WHERE booleanColumn = true
    AND parentid = parenttable.id
);
```

When this is run `parenttable.booleanColumn` gets set to true if any associated value for `childtable.booleanColumn` is true, and set to false if all associated values for `childtable.booleanColumn` are false.

I need the run the same query on SQL Server but have not been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close.  You need a `case` statement:

```
UPDATE parenttable 
    SET booleanColumn = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                           FROM childtable c
                                           WHERE c.booleanColumn = 1 AND
                                                 c.parentid = parenttable.id
                                          )
                              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, thanks. Note it should be  c.booleanColumn = 1 rather than c.booleanColumn = true